# Explicit Locks and Condition Variables Java Producer Consumer

Tags: java, multithreading, condition-variable

I am trying to run a producer consumer example which I obtained from http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/essential/threads/explicitlocks.html, the code is below. When I run it, it just runs two times and seems to be hanging. The code seems to be unlocking and signaling properly, do anyone know what I am missing.

```
    static Thread t1;
static Thread t2;


public static void main(String[] args){
    Lab2 r1=new Lab2();
    Lab2 r2=new Lab2();


    t1=new Thread(r1, "producer");
    t2= new Thread(r2, "consumer");
    //System.out.println("Adding");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

}



public int get(int who) {

    aLock.lock();
    System.out.println("locked1");

    try {
        while (available == false) {

            try {
                System.out.println("false avail waiting");

                condVar.await();
                System.out.println("false avail waiting done");

            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        available = false;
        System.out.println("Consumer " + who + " got: " +
                            contents);
        condVar.signalAll();
    } finally {
        aLock.unlock();
        return contents;
    }
}

public void put(int who, int value) {


                aLock.lock();
                System.out.println("locked");

try {
    while (available == true) {
        System.out.println("true avail");
        try {
            condVar.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }
    contents = value;
    available = true;
    System.out.println("Producer " + who + " put: " +contents);
    condVar.signalAll();
    //condVar.signal();
    } finally {
        aLock.unlock();

    }
}


public void run() {
    //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Thread started");
    int i=0;
    //System.out.println("Adding");

    while(i<10){
        i++;
        //System.out.println(i);
        if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("producer")){
        get(2);
        //producer();
        }
        else{
        put(2,1);
        //consumer();
        }
        //break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What code are you running? You posted two methods but we have no idea how you use them.

Comment: Yaroslav, thanks. I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
Lab2 r1=new Lab2();
Lab2 r2=new Lab2();

t1=new Thread(r1, "producer");
t2= new Thread(r2, "consumer");
```

I.e. you have two threads executing independent runnables (r1, r2) but they should be provided with the same runnable.

Replace it with:

```
Lab2 r=new Lab2();

t1=new Thread(r, "producer");
t2= new Thread(r, "consumer");
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved me at least a hour.